# How to match rows on only dates (not datetime), and on multiple values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet called `Transactions` in which I keep track of:

- stock buys, sells, and received dividends
- interest payments on cash acccounts

Dividend payments are marked in column `C` as `Div`, interest payments as `Int`:

```
    ---+---------------------+--------+---------+--------+
       |         A           |    B   |    C    |    D   |
    ---+---------------------+--------+---------+--------+
    1  | Date                | Ticker |  Action | Amount |
    2  | 15.11.2023 23:00:12 | MSFT   |  Buy    | 600    |
    3  | 16.11.2023 00:00:00 | ABR    |  Div    | 2.40   |
    4  | 17.11.2023 06:22:32 | ABR    |  Buy    | 60.50  |
    5  | 17.11.2023 14:00:00 | ORCL   |  Div    | 3.12   |
    6  | 17.11.2023 16:00:00 | CWSC   |  Div    | 0.88   |
    7  | 17.11.2023 00:00:00 | UBS    |  Int    | 23.50  |
    8  | 20.11.2023 17:47:21 | ING    |  Int    | 7.80   |
    9  | 20.11.2023 18:00:00 | KO     |  Sell   | 110.14 |
    10 | 21.11.2023 22:54:11 | PEP    |  Div    | 6.51   |
    ---+---------------------+--------+---------+--------+
```

On another sheet called `Income` I want to see how much dividends and interest (`Div` + `Int`) I received per day, for instance for `17.11.2023`. The expected sum here should be (3.12 + 0.88 + 23.50) `27.50`:

```
=sumproduct(Transactions!A:A="17.11.2023",Transactions!C:C="Div",Transactions!D:D)
```

This formula does not return what I need, for two reasons:

- It only selects `Div` rows. My question is: how can I make it select also the `Int` rows?
- It returns `0` rows always because I am trying to match a date (`17.11.2023`) with a datetime (for example `17.11.23 06:22:32`). How can I select only the date part of the values in column `A`?

[EDIT]

Eventually, I would run this formula in a calendar for every day of the year, like this:

[image]

Comment: Are they true `date/time` value or just texts?

Comment: true `date/time` (in custom format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try (works ***ONLY*** if its a valid datetime in Column_A):*

```js
=arrayformula(sumifs(Transactions!D:D, regexmatch(Transactions!C:C,"Div|Int"),true, int(Transactions!A:A),date(2023,11,17)))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! This works as expected. I am running this formula for every day of the year (see screenshot in opening post). So I have dragged it down and right, running 365 copies of the formula. Is there a way to make the formula run itself in all other cells, except in `C4` where the formula is running? The formula in C2 is now `=arrayformula(sumifs(Transactions!$AA:$AA, regexmatch(Transactions!$F:$F,"Div|Int"),true, int(Transactions!$A:$A),date($A$3,$B4,C$3)))`. As you can see, I'm taking the `day`, `month` and `year` values from the table headers.

Comment: Share a test sheet recreating the scenario to work on...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `QUERY()` function. Try-

```
=QUERY(HSTACK(INDEX(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A2:A),"")),B2:D),
"select sum(Col4) where Col1=" & DATE(2023,11,17) & "and Col3 matches 'Div|Int' label sum(Col4) ''")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use FILTER and REGEXMATCH

```
=sum(IF(A3<>"";FILTER(Transactions!D2:D100;REGEXMATCH(Transactions!A2:A100;A3);REGEXMATCH(Transactions!C2:C100;"buy|div"))))
```

[image]